# pfsense masquerede connection via OpenVpn

Tags: pfsense

I've a remote site that accpet traffic only from my static address. On my pfsense LAN all works fine but if I try from my home, via OpenVpn connection I can't.

In my openVpn config I push a route to a specific ip and on pfsense side I see that traffic flow from my laptop throw pfsense but the ip used to connect on remote side it's the openVpn ip and not External gateway.

I try to reproduce the schema:
external IP   1.2.3.4
LAN           192.168.1.0/24
OpenVPNLan    192.168.2.0/24
remote IP     1.1.2.2

If I try to connect from LAN on firewall i see a connection like
1.2.3.4 -> 1.1.2.2

If I try from laptop via openVpn
192.168.2.1 > 1.1.2.2

My goal is to "masqureade" 192.168.2.x to my external IP 1.2.3.4